# erlang-sqlite3 How to execute insert statement with binded parameters

Tags: sqlite, erlang

I have tried to execute prepared insert statement and cannot find function that could execute prepared code.

Lets create a test db:

open database:

```
{ok,Pid3} = sqlite3:open(db3).
```

Create table:

```
Sql1 =<<"CREATE TABLE test (
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
           ts TEXT default (datetime('now')),
           key TEXT,
           val TEXT
           );">>.
sqlite3:sql_exec(db3,Sql1).
```

Prepare insert statement with parameters:

```
Sql2. =<<"insert into test (key,val) values (@p_key,@p_val);">>.
{ok,B1} = sqlite2:prepare(db3,Sql2).
```

Now bind values:

```
 sqlite3:bind(db3,B1,[{'@p_key',<<"test_key2">>},{'@p_val',<<"test_val2">>}]).
```

Looks like the only function that fits is:
      `sql_exec(db(), iodata(), [sql_value() | {atom() | string() | integer(), sql_value()}])`

but it does not accept Bind reference (pid())

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try this myself, but according to SQLite [docs](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html), you need to call `sqlite3_step` C function on the prepared statement to run it. Looks like this function is mapped to `sqlite3:next/2` in erlang-sqlite3, so I think you need to do this

```
sqlite3:next(db3, R1). %% Is it R1 or B1?
```